Ubuntu 24.04 keyboard layout
I need to find a way to define my new keyboard in Ubuntu 24, but cannot find a way to do so. I have a Yelandar 43312428MM

Ubuntu 24 would be a version of Ubuntu Core. Ubuntu uses a xx.xx version number.

Your question is not clear and is not answerable in its current form. Please edit your question and add the following information. The full version of Ubuntu. Is it a desktop or a server, or a cloud instance? Are you trying to add a keyboard layout for a different language? If so, what language and keyboard layout did you select when you installed Ubuntu? Which new keyboard language layout are you trying to install? If you are trying to add a new physical keyboard. Describe what you have tried and error messages you get if any.

Does the new keyboard have an USB dongle? Open a terminal and enter the command lsusb without plugging in the USB dongle. Now plug in the dongle and wait for a few seconds and enter the same command again. Copy all the output from both the commands and paste it directly in your question. Then format the pasted text as code using the {_} icon above the edit window.
